# Universal Selection Color Change WinForms Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, themes, selection

***Overview***

I am currently working on a theme system for my application allowing Light and Dark themes for users to choose from (similar to visual studio). The entire process is pretty straight forward so far; however there are a few things that I'm still having a couple issues (well, more of wanting to know if there are better ways to do it). During the process of development I have put in quite a bit of research into changing the selection color of controls that support it (`ListView`, `ComboBox`, `ListBox`, `TextBox`, `RichTextBox`, etc). I have found that the most straight forward way of accomplishing this (especially with list style controls) is to perform custom drawing of the items by utilizing the events available for each control. I know that `RichTextBox` has the `SelectionBackColor` property that will allow you to change it's [selection color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor(v=vs.110).aspx), however the `TextBox` control does not offer this same property, nor anything similar that I have found.

With the `ListBox` control, it does not contain any sort of selection color property for further customization, meaning I have to utilize `OwnerDraw` and the `DrawItem`/`DrawSubItem` events to custom paint the back color while setting the `HideSelection` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false` to help with the change when focus is lost.

The `ComboBox` and `ListBox` controls are simple enough to change by utilizing the `DrawItem` event and setting it up for `OwnerDraw` like the `ListBox` control.

As we all know there are many different controls that support user selection, and I could go on and on into my research, but I think what I have supplied is enough to help describe why I am here.

***The Question***

Since the code to manipulate all of this via a single class is seriously tedious, and restrictive to future developers (especially if they are performing custom drawing of items in these controls). I am wondering if there is a simplified way to manipulate just the selection color. I have already found a post here on StackOverflow that utilizes `DllImport` to manipulate the system highlight color; however, changing things at the OS level doesn't seem like a smart, nor safe thing to do for something so simple. I am just as reluctant to manipulate system code as I am to blindly manipulate kernel registers in MIPS Assembly.

The post I found on StackOverflow utilized:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, uint[] lpaRgbValues);


void ChangeSelectColour(Color color) {
    const int COLOR_HIGHLIGHT = 13;
    const int COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT = 14;
    // You will have to set the HighlightText colour if you want to change that as well.

    //array of elements to change
    int[] elements = { COLOR_HIGHLIGHT };

    List<uint> colours = new List<uint>();
    colours.Add((uint)ColorTranslator.ToWin32(color));

    //set the desktop color using p/invoke
    SetSysColors(elements.Length, elements, colours.ToArray());
}
```

Is this the only way of doing this? If so I can abandon the idea of changing the selection color throughout the application since this doesn't seem too safe (unless someone can prove otherwise).

My current implementation (the hard way referred to in the overview section) is like this (just a small sample):

```
public static void ApplyStyles(Control c) {
    if (c is Button) {
        Button b = (Button)c;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    }
    if (c is RoundedPanel || c is PictureBox) {
        // Do nothing.
    } else {
        if (c is Label) {
            if (c.Parent is RoundedPanel) {
                // Do nothing.
            } else {
                c.BackColor = BackColor;
                c.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            }
        } else {
            c.BackColor = BackColor;
            c.ForeColor = ForeColor;
        }

        if (c is ListView) {
            ListView lv = (ListView)c;

            // PSEUDO BEGIN
            lv.OwnerDraw = true;
            lv.DrawItem += DrawListViewItem;
            lv.DrawSubItem += DrawListViewSubItem;
            // PSEUDO END

            if (Style = Themes.Dark)
                lv.GridLines = false;

            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items) {
                lvi.BackColor = BackColor;
                lvi.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you could imagine having to do that for every type that supports user selection, you end up with several conditions on a generic type that then create custom events to paint the items contained inside the control, which can get even more difficult when you start looking into the support for images, check boxes, so on, and so forth. This code can expand far and wide pretty rapidly if there aren't any generic methods to change the selection color, and in my case wouldn't be worth the effort to do (unless I made it a very low priority and worked on it occasionally through the years).

Also, keep in mind when you make suggestions; I work in a government environment so third party products all have to be approved, and in my case, a 100% solid reason as to why we need that product would have to be supplied for approval so third party theming products wouldn't really help in my case.

I thank you all for taking the time to read this, and if anyone has any ideas, please feel free to let me know!

***NOTE***

If you feel I left out any needed information, or if I should be any clearer on certain things, feel free to comment and let me know so that I can update the clarity of the post for future readers.

***References***

---

***RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor***

> Use `SelectionBackColor` to get or set the color of selected text in the `RichTextBox`. If no text is currently selected, the `SelectionBackColor` property applies to the current position of the caret. Characters that are entered from that position have the specified `SelectionBackColor`.

***ComboBox.DrawItem***

> This event is used by an owner-drawn `ComboBox`. You can use this event to perform the tasks needed to draw items in the `ComboBox`.

***ListBox.DrawItem***

> This event is used by an owner-drawn ListBox. The event is only raised when the DrawMode property is set to DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed or DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable. You can use this event to perform the tasks needed to draw items in the ListBox.

---

***Additional Links***

---

[ComboBox.DrawItem Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should take t... oh, great question! I also ran into this problem. There are two suggestions i can give you: 1. if you plan to expand `ApplyStyles` you should use a `switch case` statement to make your code more readable. 2. We decided it would be too much effort for too little yield. So we fell back on Syncfusion or DevExpress. They provide controls with extended configuration possibilities.

Comment: TextBox is a legacy control that doesn't like being changed around. - Is moving to WPF an option? Winforms as a whole is somewhat legacy and such profound changes are a lot of hassle, as you are finding..

Comment: @TaW We are considering moving to WPF in the future, but that's a few years away. I know that WPF makes things like this much easier as it can be set inline with attributes on the controls like in HTML with CSS.

Comment: @Pulle I've looked into DevExpress for these possibilities, it seems to be a pretty large tool set. I believe I'll recommend it at our next design meeting for our future redesign and see what they say. I know it'll come down to funding on that one. The justification is definitely there as we shouldn't have to create our own tools (and we are looking into other options).

Comment: • You can take a look at some open source libraries like [Metro Framework](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework) or [Krypton](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton). You can use them or at least get some idea about the way those control libraries support theme.  • Also in Windows Forms, `ToolStrip`, `StatusStrip`, `Menu` and `ContextMenuStrip` controls and `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`, `ProfessionalColorTable` are a good model of them support which you can follow.